# Complex Lookup and Replace

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vlookup

I have quite a complex task to complete with customer pricelists, which basically is a “gap filling” exercise.  Below is a sample of how the pricelists are setup within the software when exported to Excel, what I would like to do is write a formula that will fill any `£0.00` prices values with a predetermined value from the `DEFAULT` list.

[image: Example]

To give you some idea of the scope, there are around 3000 products and 800 customer pricelists to run through, so it’s a very, very big task to be done manually.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please consider reading <https://stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Comment: You could replace zeroes with blanks and then select the blanks using SpecialCells and use e.g. =C2, and press Ctrl and Enter.

Comment: You cannot use a formula to modify a cell itself (would give you a circula reference), but you could introduce a helper column that contains either the customer or the default price. Something like `=IF(D2>0,D2,C2). If you don't want to do so, you will have to write some VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Adjust ranges and formula to suit.

```
Sub x()

With Range("B2:C8")
    .Replace 0, "", xlWhole
    on error resume next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1"
End With

End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Without VBA? ;)

Comment: @JvdV - I should have clarified, you could do this as per my comment above, and I could spell out the steps if OP wants.

Comment: I's a very quick and nice solution either way!

Comment: I have tested this and it is working perfectly!  So many thanks!